# How do I find the complex number between these two points?

Tags: complex-numbers

We are given that $z_1$ has a magnitude of 1 and argument of $\theta$ while $z_2$ is $\sqrt{3}iz_1$. I am required to find $z_2-z_1$ which is fairly straightforward however, multiple choice states that the solution is $2e^{(\frac{2\pi}{3}+\theta)i}$.

I know that $z_1$ can be expressed as $e^{i\theta}$ and $z_2$ as $\sqrt{3}e^{(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})i}$.

With pythagoras, I know that the magnitude of the desired complex number is 2, however, I have no idea as to how we have brought in $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: "I know that $z_1$ can be expressed as $e^{i\theta}$ and $z_2$ as $e^{(\theta + \pi/2)i}$." ... that's where the problem is. $z_2 = \sqrt{3}e^{i(\cdots)}$

Comment: On the Argand diagram, the triangle you "drew" to find the length of $  \ z_2 - z_1 \ $ (the hypotenuse) also shows you that the angle opposite $ \ z_1 \ $ is $ \ \frac{\pi}{6} \ \ . $ So the hypotenuse makes an angle $ \ \frac{\pi}{6} \ $ to the direction of $ \ z_2 \ \ . $ The direction of $ \ z_2 - z_1 \ $ is then $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{6} \ $ relative to $ \ z_1 \ \ . $

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Here is one possible approach you can apply to such exercise:

\begin{align*}
z_{2} - z_{1} & = i\sqrt{3}z_{1} - z_{1}\\\\
& = z_{1}(-1 + i\sqrt{3})\\\\
& = 2z_{1}\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\\\\
& = 2z_{1}\left[\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right]\\\\
& = 2\cos\left(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + 2i\sin\left(\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

$\displaystyle z_1 = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).$

$\displaystyle z_2 = \sqrt{3}i ~[\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)]$

$\displaystyle = \sqrt{3} ~\left[-\sin(\theta) + i\cos(\theta)\right].$

Therefore,

$$z_2 - z_1 = [ ~-\sqrt{3}\sin(\theta) - \cos(\theta) ~] + i ~[ ~\sqrt{3}\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta)~]. \tag1 $$

---

The challenge is to express $(z_2 - z_1)$ in the form $re^{i\alpha}.$

The first thing to do is compute the *norm* of $(z_2 - z_1)$, (i.e. $|z_2 - z_1|$), where the norm of $(x + iy)$ equals $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

From (1) above, you have that $|z_2 - z_1|^2$

$ = 3\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2 (\theta) + 6\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$

$ + ~3\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) - 6\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta).$

Therefore,

$|z_2 - z_1|^2 = 3[\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta)] + [\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta)] = 3 + 1 = 4.$

Therefore, expressing $(z_2 - z_1) = re^{i\alpha},$ you have that $r = \sqrt{4} = 2.$

---

Using (1) above, with the value of $r = 2$, the
final challenge is to find the angle $\alpha$ such that

$$\cos(\alpha) = \left[-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ~\sin(\theta) ~-~ \frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta) ~\right] \tag2$$

and

$$\sin(\alpha) = \left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ~\cos(\theta) ~-~ \frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta) ~\right] \tag3$$

Examining (2) above, note that the coefficients

$~\displaystyle a = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, b = \frac{1}{2},~~$ are such that $a^2 + b^2 = 1.$

This is not a coincidence, but is in fact a consequence of the way that $r = |z_2 - z_1|$ was computed.

This means that if you can find an angle $\beta$ whose sine and cosine functions appropriately match $a$ and $b$, then you can express the RHS of (2) above as

$\cos(\beta)\cos(\theta) - \sin(\beta)\sin(\theta).$

This will allow you to express (2) above as

$\cos(\alpha) = \cos(\beta + \theta).$

You are looking for an angle $\beta$ such that

$~\displaystyle \cos(\beta) = -\frac{1}{2}, ~~\text{and}~~ \sin(\beta) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \implies \beta = \frac{2\pi}{3}.$

Verifying (3) above, you have that

$\sin(\alpha) = \sin(\beta)\cos(\theta) + \cos(\beta)\sin(\theta) = \sin(\beta + \theta).$

Therefore, you have expressed $(z_2 - z1)$ as

$r ~[ ~\cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha) ~],$

where $~r = 2~$ and $~\alpha = (2\pi/3) + (\theta).$